# Calling JS functions in dropdownList

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have coded functions to displayData from JSON and have different ones in dropdown list so user can select what they want to see.

```
   <div class="ex-basic-2">
        <label for="Charts">Sort your Data:</label>

<select name="Charts" id="chartData_Chage" onchange="changeData(this)">
  <option value="1">Top 5 Countries - Heights Cases</option>
  <option value="2">Top 5 Countries - Heights Deaths</option>
  <option value="3">Top 5 Countries - Most Recovered</option>
  <option value="4">All Countries - Cases</option>
</select>
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="chart" style="height: 400px ; width: 800px;"></canvas>
        </div> <!-- end of container -->
    </div>
```

JS :

```
var menu = document.getElementById("chartData_Chage")
menu.addEventListener("onchange", changeData)

function changeData(menu)
{
    if (menu.value == '1')
    {
        createBarChart()
    } 
    else if (menu.value == '2')
    {
        createBarChartMostDeaths()
    }
    else if (menu.value == '3')
    {
        createBarChartMostRecoverys()
    }

}
```

When I select the drop down box the methods work correct but when I move off it and hover over the bar chat data the data changes (differnt one gets call)

Any ideas whats wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `onchange="changeData(this)"` from the select

ALso it is `change` not `onchange`

Also you can use `this`:

```
function changeData() { 
   if (this.value == '1') createBarChart(); 
   else if (this.value == '2') createBarChartMostDeaths()
...
```

```js
const createBarChart = () => {
  console.log("create")
}
const createBarChartMostDeaths = () => {
  console.log("create most deaths")
}
const createBarChartMostRecoverys = () => {
  console.log("create most recoveries")
}


function changeData() {
  if (this.value == '1') {
    createBarChart()
  } else if (this.value == '2') {
    createBarChartMostDeaths()
  } else if (this.value == '3') {
    createBarChartMostRecoverys()
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  const menu = document.getElementById("chartData_Change")
  menu.addEventListener("change", changeData); // "change" not "onchange"
  menu.value=1;
  createBarChart()
})
```

```html
<div class="ex-basic-2">
  <label for="Charts">Sort your Data:</label>

  <select name="Charts" id="chartData_Change">
    <option value="1">Top 5 Countries - Heights Cases</option>
    <option value="2">Top 5 Countries - Heights Deaths</option>
    <option value="3">Top 5 Countries - Most Recovered</option>
    <option value="4">All Countries - Cases</option>
  </select>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="chart" style="height: 400px ; width: 800px;"></canvas>
  </div>
  <!-- end of container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Yeah only starting to learn JS my JS code layout is all over the place atm. Quick question how would I have it set that Value 1 on the drop down list is always Called at the start ? @mplungjan

Answer (score 1):

you only need to set the event in your select tag, like this

```
<select id="sel" onchange='changeData(this)'>
```

here is a complete example : (https://jsfiddle.net/eaxv0o12/)